# I need a very simple search gem for just searching the partyname on a sqlight3 database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, search, rubygems

My party registry Rails 3 app needs a search function for visitors to search a partyname and then be able to click on the party and go to the show page of that party. Must be very simple ajax list that pops up without reloading etc.

The app is almost done and runs off a sqlight3 database.

Any suggestions - tried all the RailsCasts ones and nothing fits right 100%.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Be more specific, which ones have you tried?

Comment: Ya the Railcasts one's are all text specifically expect simple search but apparently doesn't really work with Rails 3 so kinda stuck.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want two different things.

1) To create a simple search you can do something like [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form).

2) To autocomplete while typing (partyname for example) you can use the [autocomplete](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete) gem.

You must decide which approach you want to follow.....

I hope if helps in some way...

**EDIT** - to show how to implement the simple search.

let's say you have a model called `Party`

your form (index page for example):

```
...
<%= form_tag parties_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
<% end %>
...

#display results
<% @parties.each do |party| %>
...
<% end %>
```

model Party:

```
...
def self.search(search)
  # if search is not empty
  if search
    find(:all, :conditions => ["partyname LIKE ?", "%#{search}%"])
  # if search is empty return all
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end
...
```

controle parties_controller:

```
@parties = Party.search(params[:search])
```

Comment: simple search works on rails 3... I have used it on my last app, I did it using Rails 3.2. I will edit the answer to give you an example...

Comment: Ok, maybe I got it wrong. Will try again. Thanks for the help. Did you install via GEM install?

Comment: in this case, you don't need to install any gem... it is all ruby code :)... any help please let me know.

Comment: Oh, thought you were talking about search logic. If I move the search away from the index to my home page and hit submit it goes to index and displays everything. How can I keep everything in the home page?

Comment: Hi.. the search form will look at your index action in the controller  parties because of `parties_path`. If you want to display the results in your home page, you need to change this path, and of course, include the `@parties = Party.search(params[:search])` inside the action you are calling with the new path... I did something similar few months ago for an assignment at UNI, if you want you can check it here: https://github.com/gabrielhilal/CI3540-ecommerce . I hope it helps...

Comment: So cool, that you can study programming! I'm learning, while being a full time husband, dad and director at a company ;) Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi, one last question hopefully. I don't want the index to show in my homepage - only when a search is done - is that possible => or rather if the search is type a short list automatically comes up. I should probably use some ajax and java for that?

Comment: Hi, in your Model you are returning all data (`find(:all)`), in case there is no search, and storing it on `@parties` variable in your controller. You can remove this `if`, but the `@parties` will became empty. So you also need to include in your `home view` an `if` like `unless @parties.nil?` to avoid the `variable nil` error. Regarding the short list that automatically comes up, you can use the autocomplete gem: https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete. Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks so much. Thinks go faster with such awesome advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try smart_search gem

```
gem install smart_search
```

Does everything that needs to be done to make your model searchable!